# Arquivo cordova.js não aparece

Tags: intel-xdk

Colegas.

Quando crio um APP no Xdk Intel com Cordova, aparece a seguinte linha:

```
<script src='cordova.js'></script>
```

Porém no diretório não aparece esse arquivo, mas tem a pasta plugins onde tem as pastas: cordova-plugin-device, cordova-plugin-splashscreen e cordova-plugin-statusbar.

Porque o arquivo cordova.js não aparece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse arquivo é gerado automaticamente quando vc faz o build, por isso vc deve referencia-lo e ele não fica em nenhuma das pastas do seu projeto.
Tem uma matéria explicando com mais detalhes

> [Testando aplicações Phonegap/Cordova](http://imasters.com.br/framework/testando-aplicacoes-phonegapcordova-muito-rapidamente-no-dispositivo-com-framework-ionic/?trace=1519021197&source=single)